NextJS Link component does not scroll to anchor element on another page
I have a link button like this:
export const FlagButton = () => {
  return (
    <Link
      href='/app/editor#features'
      target='_blank'
      className='flex'
      scroll={false}
    >
      <MenuButton
        icon={<FlagIcon className='[&_path]:!fill-red-500' />}
        tooltip={{ content: <TooltipContent title={_t('commands.flag')} /> }}
      />
    </Link>
  );
};

I expected that once I click it, it will scroll to the features section in the /app/editor page but its not the case and the top of the page is visible. I tried with a tag and it does not work ass well. Any ideas how to fix that?

Hi @Korer can you confirm if the feature section on your /app/editor page has an id of #features ? If not, you need to give it the same id and that should solve your problem

Of course I've used <section id="features"/>

Ah, I see. Can you create a codesandbox to illustrate this?
